# Android Studio No Longer Connects to Debugging Phone

Tags: android-studio, androidphone

I have been emailed by GooglePlay to update my app to set `targetSDK` to 33. It has been a while since I last opened Android Studio.

When I updated this to 33 and clicked the debug icon, **it starts and then finishes debugging immediately without the programming running on the phone**.

I checked my phone and **"Debugging by USB"** was not connected. So I corrected that.

Resetting **"Debugging by USB"** made my phone appear in the **connected devices** select box in Android Studio. **But it appeared grey.**

Clicking the debug icon still results in the program not running on the phone and the **debugger starting and finishing in a second without doing anything** with the program not starting on the phone as it should.

My Android phone is running Android 7.0.

Have I forgotten to do something?